# Power consumption

Tags: charging, telephone

A phone charger is rated with input of AC 240v 50/60Hz 0.35 amps will it accept only 240 v 0.35 or will it take full 240 v 16 amps and step it down please I am very new to electrical stuff please help I am really confused.

Comment: The deal is that you supply it with 240V and it will decide how many Amps it wants to take. If the rating says 0.35A, then it may take 0.35 or it may take a bit less. For something like this, just worry about the voltage.

Comment: google `ohm's law`  to learn the relationship between voltage, resistance, current and power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit may be capable of delivering 16 Amps, but any load will only draw the current it requires - so your phone charge will draw 0.35 Amp (or less, depenidng on the state of charge of the phone).